# Label edges of Forest tree leaves to a free node

Tags: nodes, forest

My current code is below, formulated directly from the forest package documentation style.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw, s sep=1cm, l sep=15mm, anchor=north west}
[A
    [B,edge label={node[midway,left, xshift=2 mm, fill=white] {1}} 
      [D,name=leaf1,edge label={node[midway,left,xshift=2 mm, fill=white] {5}} ] 
      [E,name=leaf2,edge label={node[midway,left,xshift=2 mm, fill=white] {7}} ] 
      [F,name=leaf3,edge label={node[midway,left,xshift=3 mm, fill=white] {12}} ]
    ]
    [C,edge label={node[midway,left,xshift=3 mm, fill=white] {27}}
      [H,name=leaf4,edge label={node[midway,left,xshift=2 mm, fill=white] {8}} ] 
      [I,name=leaf5,edge label={node[midway,left,xshift=2 mm, fill=white] {2}} ] 
      [J,name=leaf6,edge label={node[midway,left,xshift=2 mm, fill=white] {9}} ]
    ] 
]
\node at (current bounding box.south)
   [below=15mm,draw,circle, name=Target]
   {T};
\draw[-] (leaf1) to (Target);
\draw[-] (leaf2) to (Target);
\draw[-] (leaf3) to (Target);
\draw[-] (leaf4) to (Target);
\draw[-] (leaf5) to (Target);
\draw[-] (leaf6) to (Target);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

What I would like to do is label the edges produced with the 6 draw commands similarly to the above labels.

Comment: Why can't you just add e.g. `node [midway, above] {label}` or whatever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very late ... but that this question not stay unanswered i elaborate [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) comment with small changes:

- for labels of lines outside of `forest` are used `tikz` library `quotes`
- for labels in tree is defined new style `EL` (as Edge Label), which make writing labels much shorter

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{forest}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{forest}
  for tree = {circle, draw,
              s sep+ = 6mm,
              l sep+ = 12mm,
           EL/.style = {edge label={node[midway, fill=white, inner sep=2pt,
                                          anchor=center]{#1}},},
            }
  [A
      [B,EL=1
        [D,name=leaf1,EL=5 ]
        [E,name=leaf2,EL=7 ]
        [F,name=leaf3,EL=12 ]
      ]
      [C,EL=27
        [H,name=leaf4,EL=8 ]
        [I,name=leaf5,EL=2 ]
        [J,name=leaf6,EL=9 ]
      ]
  ]
  \tikzset{every edge quotes/.style = {fill=white, inner sep=2pt}}
  \node[below=20mm of current bounding box.south,
        circle, draw, name=Target] {T};
  \draw   (leaf1) edge ["A"] (Target)
          (leaf2) edge ["B"] (Target)
          (leaf3) edge ["C"] (Target)
          (leaf4) edge ["D"] (Target)
          (leaf5) edge ["E"] (Target)
          (leaf6) edge ["F"] (Target);
  \end{forest}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]